# Где хранятся значения артибутов в бд?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

При импорте товаров в WC столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо создать на новом сайте атрибуты и их значения для товаров. Вся сложность заключается в том, что товаров очень много, соответственно у атрибутов имеются огромное количество значений. Вносить их вручную не представляется возможным, к сожалению, ввиду их большого количества. Импортировать атрибуты невозможно, однако, есть одна идея - попробовать внести эти атрибутом через mysql. Я нашел в бд где хранятся сами атрибуты, а вот где у нас лежат их значения отыскать не смог, поэтому обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Если импортировать товары с атрибутами до того момента, как они будут на сайте, то фильтр товаров работать не будет. В этом и заключается основная проблема.

Comment: Они хранятся в `wp_term_relationships`, но от этого знания не легче: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56174733/6817117

Comment: Забудьте как страшный сон идею лезть в базу своими mysql запросами. Раз вы не можете найти, как хранятся атрибуты, то всё, чего вы добъётесь своими запросами - сломаете базу. Используйте плагины или средства самого WC, как описано в ответах.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Используй класс WC_Product

Добавляешь атрибуты через set_attributes и потом сохраняешь через метод save

Answer (score 0):

> однако, есть одна идея - попробовать внести эти атрибутом через
>   mysql.

Идея плохая, я бы даже сказал безумная. 
Импортировать товары *вместе* с атрибутами нужно либо родным механизмом WC ибо с пом специальных плагинов.

> Если импортировать товары с атрибутами до того момента, как они будут
>   на сайте, то фильтр товаров работать не будет. В этом и заключается
>   основная проблема.

Это что-то...
После импорта товары стразу будут "на сайте".

Comment: После импорта товары будут на сайте, но их атрибуты через фильтр отображаться не будут, так как при импорте товаров атрибуты и их значения в разделе Товары->Атрибуты не фиксируются. http://ybex.com/d/09pwccppt7pv925020cm7sqd9yg8rvgaxrwk1twu.html

Родной механизм WC не позволяет переносить значения артибутов в поле, которое я отметил выше в скрине. А вот уже фильтр поиска использует значения как раз из этого поля.

Comment: @Aptero, если плагин фильтрации не правильно работает. что надо менять плагин. Или написать разрабам о такой проблеме. Но кроме того можно использовать импорт товара не родным механизмом, а с пом плагинов коих не мало.